# How to change the UISearchBar from round to rectangular?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UISearchBar: Changing the appearance - Shape, Background, Overlay an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370002/uisearchbar-changing-the-appearance-shape-background-overlay-an-image)

How do I change the `UISearchBar` shape from round to rectangular? I'm using this through storyboards, with  `UISearchBar` as an `IBOutlet`.